# Is there a way to transform language to locale?

Tags: python, netsuite

I was wondering if there is a simple way in python to transfer pycountry.language.alpha2 strings like 'en', 'de', 'cs'... to locales i.e. strings like 'en_US', 'de_DE', 'cs_CZ' and so on.

Even wonder if there exists a unambiguous translation.

To be more specific I need this, because we store language in ISO639-1 format but netsuite rest api requires locale and they somehow determine language of invoice by that...

Comment: How to decide whether to use `en_US` or `en_UK` and any other the other `en_*`, `de_*`, etc.?

Comment: Lazy solution: find the first locale that starts with "en" and return that.

Comment: `en_*` is a *more specific* version of `en`. There's no unambiguous translation of something generic into something more specific, unless there's only one specific sub-item.

Comment: Edited post so it makes a bit more sense now I hope. But yes that is what I was worried about.

Comment: Sounds plainly like a stupid, locale-ignorant bug in Netsuite, and not really something you can work around properly without their cooperation.  If I wanted my invoice in Esperanto or Cherokee, which geographic area do you think they would like me to choose ...? This also works badly when you are an expat and/or for other reasons don't necessarily speak the majority language of the region where you are stationed. *n*(languages) >> *n*(regions with an ISO code) and also *n*(languages spoken in any one of those regions) >> 1

Comment: Well point is that their api is kinda stupidly written for example for Arabic the rest parameter is 'ar' for Armenian it is 'hy_AM' and I don't know about any ISO standard that looks this way.

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, found out that Netsuite uses kinda stupid non standardized format in their rest api, so I will need to configure it myself somehow. Thanks for all suggestions. And sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: It could be worthwhile to you post your solution, if/when you find one.

Comment: I am working on one now. Will try to post general version of that.